# How to change table rows by table name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write an sql script that :
find all the tables that has a column named: sister
then, add all the rows in these tables in the column sister what was there + *

for example
Family table:

```
brother sister mother
m        b       c
k         r     p
```

result would change that table to

```
brother sister mother
m        b*      c
k         r*     p
```

if there were more tables with sister columns it should do that to them either.
if there were more table withous siter column it should not touch them.

thanks a lot for help

Comment: They want to add an asterisk to the end of every value that is in a column named sister in any table...  `Update Table Set Sister = Sister + '*'` but it sounds like he wants to do this dynamically for all tables that have a sister column

Comment: What if the value already ends in a `*`? What if the value is already at max column length and so no room to append an extra character?

Comment: @MartinSmith so if it has to add also but if you cant because max or something so not

Comment: Use system tables to identify all tables having column with name sister. `SELECT concat('UPDATE ', Table_name, ' set sister = sister+'*')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE columN_Name ='sister' and TABLE_SCHEMA='YourSchemaName'`  you could modify the select statement to dynamically generate the table updates.  above is close if not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' + COLUMN_NAME
       + '= ' + COLUMN_NAME + '+''*'''
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME'
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
```

Comment: this is not executable @paul

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, you would need to use dynamic SQL to accomplish this. I don't recommend that. It's better to know which tables you're updating instead of relying on the database to know. There might be one table where you don't want an update.

However; the below code will accomplish your request of finding all columns named "sister" on all tables, and appending an asterisk to the end of the value stored there. I don't use a cursor. I create the UPDATE statements as a single transaction.

```
-- Table variable to hold update statments:
declare @sqlUpdates table (
                           ID   int           not null identity(1,1)
                         , stmt nvarchar(max) not null
                          );

-- Populate all the update statements at once:
insert @sqlUpdates (stmt)
select 'update ['
     + schema_name(tables.schema_id)
     + '].['
     + tables.name
     + '] set sister = sister + ''*'''
  from sys.tables
  join sys.columns
    on columns.object_id = tables.object_id
 where columns.name = 'sister'

-- Loop throug & execute update statement
declare @min int = (select min(ID) from @sqlUpdates);
declare @stmt nvarchar(max);

while @min is not null
begin;

   -- Get the update statement from the table variable
   set @stmt = (select stmt from @sqlUpdates where ID = @min);

   -- execute the update:
   exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt;

   -- Increment the loop:
   set @min = (select min(ID) from @sqlUpdates where ID > @min)

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you needed another option with *flexibility of changing column name at one place*:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100) = 'sister'
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000) 

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT '['+C.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+C.TABLE_NAME+']' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE @ColumnName 
    AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET '+ @ColumnName +' = '+ @ColumnName + ' + ''*''' 

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Comment: In general, you should avoid cursors. You should include schema-qualified table names (there may be more than one table of the same name). You should set (but not declare) a variable inside the loop. use sp_executesql instead of EXEC @SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)